# React crashes without displaying error when user selects one option but then changes it to another option

Tags: reactjs, crash, html-select, conditional-rendering

My code is working when a user selects any of the options.

However, when they select the *'now'* option and then change their mind and select the *'specific'* option, React crashes without displaying an error - it just shows a white screen.

This problem doesn't occur when the options are selected the other way round - when *'specific'* is selected and the user changes their mind and selects *'now'*.

When *'specific'* is selected a new input is rendered.

A simplified version of the code is below:

```
render() {

let startSelling = values.tickets.map((e,i) => {
    if(e.startSelling == 'specific'){
        return(
                <div>                 
                    <DatePicker
                        className="datePicker"
                        timeIntervals={15}
                        onChange={event => this.props.setSpecificTime(event, i, 'startSellingTime', values)}
                        selected={values.tickets[i].startSellingTime}
                        placeholderText='Select Date And Time'
                        showTimeSelect
                        dateFormat="Pp"
                        />
                </div>
        )
    }else{return <div></div>}
})


return (
    <>

        {this.state.tickets.map((e, i) => {
            return (
            <div>
                <div>       
                    <select
                        value={values.tickets[i].startSelling}
                        onChange={event => this.props.changeSellingTimes(event, i, 'startSelling', 'startSellingTime', values)}
                    >
                        <option value='' disabled>Start Selling Tickets</option>
                        <option value="now">Now</option>
                        <option value="specific">Specific Date and Time</option>
                        {i===1 ? <option value="whenPreviousSoldOut">When {values.tickets[0].ticketType} Is Sold Out</option>:<option value="whenPreviousSoldOut" disabled={i==0}>When A Previous Ticket Is Sold Out</option>}  
                    </select>
                </div>
                {startSelling[i]}
        </div>
            )
            
        })}

    </>

)
```

}

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is it returning that empty div in your first conditional statement (`if(e.startSelling == 'specific')`? It's easy to test, just type "hello" in that div then run your app again

Comment: Yes, that's working

Comment: Found it. Selecting 'now' was saving a date as a moment object in state. Datepicker caused react to crash when it tried to read it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad you got it. Too bad that didn't log the error for you lol.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Selecting 'now' was saving a date as a moment object in state. Datepicker caused react to crash when it tried to read it.